# I want to make a game with Pygame.But my arrow can't shoot from the right position

Tags: python, pygame

Python version: 3.8.1

System: Windows7-32bit

see the title,i want to make a game,but i ,meet a problem.Arrows fired by players do not appear in the correct position.No matter how the player's position changes, the arrow will always shoot from one position.
I didn't used a group,because I find it not enough to make game.
Please help me!

There are some code:

**steve_vs_monsters.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import Settings
import key_event
from steve import Steve
from update_screen import screen_update
from arrow import Arrow

def run_game():
    """ """
    --snip--
    #
    steve = Steve(a_settings,screen)
    arrow = Arrow(a_settings,screen,steve)
    #
    arrows = []

    #
    while True: 
        #
        key_event.check_events(steve,arrow,arrows)
        #
        update_screen(a_settings,screen,steve,arrow,arrows)

run_game()
```

**arrow.py**

```
import pygame

class Arrow():
    """ """
    def __init__(self,a_settings,screen,steve):
        """ """
        --snip--
        #
        self.rect.centerx = steve.rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = steve.rect.top
        self.rect.left = steve.rect.right
        #
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    def draw_arrow(self,arrows):
        """ """
        for a_arrow in arrows:
            self.screen.blit(self.image,a_arrow[0:2])

    def update_rect(self,steve,arrows):  
        for a_arrow in arrows:
            a_arrow[0] += float(self.a_settings.arrow_speed)

            if a_arrow[0] > self.screen_rect.right:
                arrows.remove(a_arrow)
```

**update_screen.py**

```
import pygame

def update_screen(a_settings,screen,steve,arrow,arrows):
    """ """
    screen.fill(a_settings.bg_color)
    steve.update_rect()
    arrow.update_rect(steve,arrows)
    steve.draw_steve()  
    arrow.draw_arrow(arrows)
    #
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**key_event.py**

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event,steve,arrow,arrows):
    """ """
    if event.key == pygame.K_t:
        sys.exit()
    --snip--
    elif event.key==pygame.K_SPACE and len(arrows)<=4:
        arrows.append([arrow.center,arrow.rect.bottom,arrow.rect.left])

--snip--

def check_events(steve,arrow,arrows):
    """ """
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,steve,arrow,arrows)
        --snip--
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code initially creates a single `arrow` that takes the position from `steve`'s rectangle.  This `arrow` is then used as the base-position for creating new arrows when `K_SPACE` is pressed.

I think that the *current* rectangle of `steve` should be used to create a new instance of `Arrow`, rather than an existing instance.

For example:

```
def check_keydown_events(event,steve,arrow,arrows):
    """ """
    if event.key == pygame.K_t:
        sys.exit()
    --snip--
    elif event.key==pygame.K_SPACE and len(arrows)<=4:
        #arrows.append( [arrow.center, arrow.rect.bottom, arrow.rect.left] )
        arrows.append( [steve.center, steve.rect.top, steve.rect.right] )
```

This way the new arrow is always created to where `steve` is positioned *now*, rather than positioned initially.

It's not clear to me why top/bottom and left/right is swapped when that first `Arrow` is created, but I have modified the code to use this method too.

Personally, I would modify the Arrow class such that it takes `x` and `y` co-ordinates, and the speed as simple parameters:

```
class Arrow():
    """ """
    def __init__( self, arrow_image, x_pos, y_pos, speed ):
        self.image = arrow_image
        self.rect  = arrow_image.get_rect()
        self.speed = speed
        self.rect.centerx = x_pos
        self.rect.centery = y_pos

    def update( self ):
        self.rect.centerx += self.speed

    @staticmethod
    def draw_arrow_set( screen, all_arrows ):
        for a in all_arrows:
            screen.blit( a.image, a.rect )

    @staticmethod
    def update_arrow_set( all_arrows, screen_rect ):  
        for a in all_arrows:
            a.update()
            if ( a.rect.centerx > screen_rect.right ):
                all_arrows.remove( a )          # doesn't this cause problems?
```

Then it is more flexible:

```
if ( steve_facing_left ):
    # facing left
    x_start = steve.rect.x    # start on Steve's left side
    arrows.append( Arrow( left_arrow_image, x_start, steve.rect.centery, -1 ) )
else:     
    # facing right
    x_start = steve.rect.x　+ steve.rect.width   # start on Steve's right side
    arrows.append( Arrow( right_arrow_image, x_start, steve.rect.centery, 1 ) )
```

And then later on:

```
arrows.append( Arrow( super_arrow_image, x_start, y_start, 3 ) )
```